# Jqueri проверка каждой ячейки

Tags: jquery

День добрый.
Как можно запустить проверку на наличие элемента .sale_price в .call_price? В данном варианте класс убирается из всех .price, а надо только в том случае если присутствует .sale_price в этой ячейке.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 5//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/html5.dtd"
        >
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            if($('.sale_price').length){
                $('.price').addClass('cross_price');
            $('.price').removeClass('price');
        }
        });

    </script>
    <style>
        .cross_price{text-decoration: line-through;}
    </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="call_price">
            <div class="price">150</div>
            <div class="sale_price">100</div>
        </div>
        <div class="call_price">
            <div class="price">20</div>
        </div>
        <div class="call_price">
            <div class="price">20</div>
        </div>
        <div class="call_price">
            <div class="price">120</div>
            <div class="sale_price">90</div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.call_price:has(.sale_price) .price').removeClass('price');
```

Comment: спасибо. работает

Comment: можно ли как то еще добавить проверку в случае если .sale_price присутствует но пустое?

попробовал так:
    $('.call_price:has(.sale_price:empty) .price')
        .addClass('cross_price')

не заработало.

Comment: Должно работать. Возможно синтаксические ошибки где-то или нет пустых .sale_price

Comment: точно) спасибо.